# SQL DISTINCT value within a field

Tags: sql

I know how to select distinct rows, but I can't find how to extract distinct 'words/string/data' from a field to update another column. 
For example, if I have data in a table like so..

Table 1

```
    ID    TEXTDATA
    123   ROCK DANCE ROCK INDIE ROCK POP DISCO EURO POP
    456   POP DANCE DISCO POP
```

I want to UPDATE another field in another table with 'distinct' data from within the TEXTDATA fields, so it would look like this

Table 2

```
    ID    NEWTEXTDATA
    123   ROCK DANCE INDIE POP DISCO EURO
    456   POP DANCE DISCO
```

I worked out how to Update one table with data from another...

```
    UPDATE table2 JOIN table1 ON table2.ID = table1.ID SET table2.NEWTEXTDATA = table1.TEXTDATA;
```

But I want it to be of distinct values within the TEXTDATA records. Hope that makes some sort of sense. Is that possible to do within an update query? 
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Don't store data like that with several items in a column, it will only cause you lots of problems! One value per row is the SQL way.

Comment: You will have to parse the column first. This might be ill performing. If it is legacy try to create a new table/view like @jarlh suggests

Comment: Hi, It's actually a caching table made up of data from other sources, used for searching. Rather than querying lots of tables and columns, the data is stored into one special cache table. But a lot of it is legacy which needs tidying so I was wondering if there was a way of doing it via SQL queries. Otherwise I can export to Excel and do it there if needs be. Thanks

Comment: Google for function split ... and split those words into rows with ID as primary key and get distinct values per ID from there ... that's the way i would go

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Sql Server 2008:**

You can do this by using the xml query with distinct values. The below code will give you the distinct records from given row.

```
cast(cast('<d>'+replace(TEXTDATA, ' ','</d><d>')+'</d>'  as xml).query('distinct-values(/d)') as varchar(max))
```

So with the help of above function your final query will be something like below.

```
UPDATE
    table2
SET
    NEWTEXTDATA = cast(cast('<d>'+replace(TEXTDATA, ' ','</d><d>')+'</d>'  as xml).query('distinct-values(/d)') as varchar(max))
FROM
    table2 t2
JOIN
    table1 t1
ON 
    t2.ID = t1.ID;
```

Here is the working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbc6f/4) for same.

**For MySql:** There is no way in MySql to achieve this.

Normalize your database.

get values from table and use php  explode() , and use array_unique to remove duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks J-D. I can see how that works on the SQL Fiddle. Thanks for doing that. I'm trying to do it via phpmyadmin though. Do I need to declare that function first though?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm on Oracle. Thanks for the pointers so far anyway. Just wanted to check if it was possible with an SQL query. I can filter in Excel and import back. Many thanks. While your solution doesn't solve my specific problem, I know it would be useful for others - hence the tick.